# socket.io, chat app using web sockets- closing tab1 results in void "online users" in tab2 and tab3

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, web-development-server

In my chat app using web-sockets, whenever more than 1 users are connected (say {user1: tab1, user2: tab2, user2: tab3, ...}), on closing tab1, "online users" status in other tabs (tab2, tab3, ...) goes empty.
However on doing opposite of that, i.e on closing a tab apart from tab1, my chat app works perfectly fine by real time updating of "online users" status in other tabs.
 I don't know exactly which part of my code is going wrong, so i am giving links to all the coding parts of index.html and server.js
[index.html](https://onlinegdb.com/BkS_EQJN4)
[server.js](https://onlinegdb.com/rJm9K7k4V)
 I am using nodejs version 10.15.0, express version 6.7.0, socket.io version 6.7.0.
I hope this much information will be sufficient.

Comment: server.js is only `print('Hello World')`

Comment: There are two tabs in server.js link. The "hello world" part is posted by mistake. Sorry about that..

Comment: I've edited the link, thanks for notifying it @Jeremy Thille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is here :

```
users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username))
```

From [Array.splice documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) :

> array.splice(start[, deleteCount])
>
> If deleteCount is omitted [...] then all of the elements from start
>   through the end of the array will be deleted.

So, when the first user disconnects, you remove them *and all the following users* from the array.

My guess is that you should write this :

```
users.splice(users.indexOf(socket.username), 1)
```

to remove only one user at a time.

Comment: ah, nice. My pleasure :)

Comment: I've one more question, I don't know exactly what tool to use to greet every user with his/her username.( say Welcome Tom on Tom's chat tab)

Comment: well that's a different question (that would deserve a new question on Stackoverflow) but why don't you just use `socket.username` ?

Comment: If you notice in index.html at line 58 to 60, i've left a span, but was unable to do.

Comment: I've tried but i am unsure of how to project that socket.username value to that specific span

Comment: What about just `$owner.text(socket.username)` ?

Comment: Can you please provide me with the complete line of code, and where to insert that line, as it doesn't seems to be working out @Jeremy

Comment: hmmm no, sorry, not here in comments. Please create a new question

Comment: Okay, Thanks Jeremy, I will be posting one soon:)